# What exactly is `Readable`, the type of stream properties in the object returned by `child_process.spawn()`?

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

```js
const child = child_process.spawn(someCommand);
const stdout = child.stdout;
```

In these two lines of code, my IDE tells me that the `stdout` property of the `child` object is of type `Readable`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to import that type so that I can use it unambiguously in JSDoc as a parameter type hint:

```js
/*
 * @param {Readable} stream
 */
function doSomethingWithStream(stream) {
    // ...
}
```

The above shows no diagnostics, but when I try to call the function:

```js
doSomethingWithStream(child.stdout);
```

... then PhpStorm shows a diagnostic for the argument: `Argument type Readable is not assignable to parameter type Readable`. This is weird: "X is not X".

I suspect this has something to do with `mocha.Readable` interfering - this is happening in a unit test file.

How can I unambiguously point JSDoc at *the* `Readable` *that* I actually have in mind, the same that is the type of the `stdout` property of the object returned by  `child_process.spawn()`?

Comment: You might try setting the type to [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable).

Comment: That didn't work, but `import {Readable} from "stream";` did, and I import it only to make the IDE happy, I don't need it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import {Readable} from "stream"; // <- this does the trick
```

The confounding factor was IDE help balloons showing it as `stream.internal.Readable` rather than `stream.Readable`.

Comment: This is a weirdness caused by your environment.  In Javascript, you don't have to import an interface in order to use that interface on an object that you are passed.  You just use the interface directly on the object you are passed.

Comment: This is not even Javascript per se, it's just JSDoc and how the IDE interprets it and what additional hints it needs to interpret it correctly. I think we are in agreement here.

Comment: So, this is just a question/answer about your IDE?  That certainly isn't what the title of your question implies.

Comment: No, it's not "just the IDE", it's "just JSDoc and the IDE", exactly as I wrote. The title is a mental snapshot of a particular stage of insight gathering, a real stage that I actually went through. It accurately represents how the problem initially presented itself to me, and note that I did not accept my own answer, because while it solves the problem, it doesn't actually answer the question. I still don't know what is going on with the `stream.Readable` vs. `stream.internal.Readable` polysemy. I found a workaround, but I don't know why it works.

Comment: Well, if you want any help with the actual question you're trying to ask, you probably need to rewrite the question to be entirely about your IDE (which I think perhaps is PHPStorm) because as best I can tell, only someone who knows about that environment would have any chance of helping you as this seems to be an environment-specific question, not a general Javascript question.  Javascript itself has none of these issues.

Comment: But I don't know for sure that any of the elements of the whole context (JS, JSDoc, `.d.ts`, IDE) is irrelevant. The question is inherently not entirely about my IDE. I **don't know** if this `internal` thing is a JS artifact, a JSDoc artifact, a `.d.ts` artifact, or an IDE artifact. I can take your word that it isn't a JS artifact strictly speaking, but that's it.

Comment: So, now you mention `.d.ts`.  Does that mean this is TypeScript?  That's an entirely different ballgame because it is typed and you do have to have type bindings for something in order to compile code that uses it.  Anyway, I will be leaving now as I have nothing further to add.  As written, your question is unlikely to attract any further attention.  I was making some suggestions on how it could/should be changed if you still actually want someone to help further.

Comment: The IDE uses type info about standard node libraries, and that type info ships in the form of `.d.ts` files - if I shift click a symbol like `Readable` in my code, it takes me to the `.d.ts` file where the type is described. I don't know how standard that method of supplying type information for JS libraries is, and which component in the whole complicated constellation of JS, JSDoc, TS and IDE is to blame for the whole thing sometimes working unpredictably.